# Looking for a short story about a fossil found on Mars

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-exploration, mars

An early (first?) expedition to Mars finds a fossil and the geologist dies trying to get it back.  The story is told by a survivor of the expedition many years later after Mars has been colonized, thanks to the interest generated by the fossil find.

Comment: A rover to a chasma, geologist found the fossil of a small marine animal proving previous life on Mars, injured in a fall that also damaged the rover, long trip back to ship in sandstorm, geologist doesn't make it but partner does, brings the fossil back knowing it will generate more interest in colonizing Mars.  Story is told by the partner now living on Mars years later.   Was published in one of the fantasy/sf magazines probably about the 90's.

Comment: I remember this one.  I think it was in the 80s, I think it was published in Asimov's, and I think the title was something like "The Carhardt Shale".  Spelling may off.  Google-fu not working.

Comment: Tha'ts it -- The Carhart Shale,  Thank you very much!  I'll track down the magazine.

Comment: Found it, thank you so much!
Grant Callin, The Carhart Shale, Analog, Oct, 1993

Comment: @Chick Please mark the answer below as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of it!

Answer (score 4):

Entering the formal answer based on the data above: Grant Callin, "[The Carhart Shale](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47245)", *Analog*, Oct, 1993

[image: Analog October 1993 cover]